# Is it possible to sync a folder from NAS drive to Ubuntu One Cloud?

Tags: ubuntu-one, mount, windows-7, backup, nas

I am running Ubuntu One on Windows 7. I have a Synology DS212+ NAS drive that I would ideally like to back up to my cloud. However, Ubuntu One only allows me to backup from the user documents folder on the computer I am running from. Is there a way to back up a folder from my NAS directly?

At the moment, I run a scheduled sync toy task to copy the folder from the NAS to the user documents folder, which then gets picked up in my nightly Ubuntu sync. This seems a bit of a hack.

Is there any way of mounting the nas folder inside the user directory?

Answer (score 2):

Currently Ubuntu One doesn't support syncing from a NAS. Also, keep in mind that it's not a backup tool, because it preserves no history, and accidental deletion on your device will cause deletion on our servers!

The suggested mechanism is doing a backup, and then syncing the backup, just like you are doing.

Comment: +1 for the "Ubuntu one is not a backup tool"